# jQuery.browser undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new in java script, this is my function and because of conflict It dosen't work fine . how should I fix this?
part1:

```
function updateme() {

    var searchIDs = [];
  $("#customers input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    searchIDs.push($(this).val());
  });
    return searchIDs;
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  setTimeout("Dajaxice.meli.refresh1(my_callback, {'text':updateme()})", 50);
}, 5000);
```

part2:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#dock').Fisheye(
            {
                maxWidth: 50,
                items: 'a',
                itemsText: 'span',
                container: '.dock-container',
                itemWidth: 40,
                proximity: 90,
                halign : 'center'
            }
        )
        $('#dock2').Fisheye(
            {
                maxWidth: 60,
                items: 'a',
                itemsText: 'span',
                container: '.dock-container2',
                itemWidth: 70,
                proximity: 50,
                alignment : 'left',
                valign: 'bottom',
                halign : 'center'
            }
        )
    }
);
```

I read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) but I don't understand how should I use It.
In firebug I see this error:

```
TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined
```

and the problem is [Fisheye](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-interface-fisheye.html) dosen't work correctly. It dosen't move

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: What makes you think there is some conflict somewhere? You have to provide as much as info as possible in order to get some help

Comment: Looks like you are using jQuery >= 1.9 where the [support for browser](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) was removed

Comment: I add more information to the post

Comment: "TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined" this error as nothing to do with any conflict... Next time, post error message initially in your post!

Comment: @nim4n what is the version of jQuery used

Comment: I can't see any other error in my firebug.@Arun P Johny  I'm using the last version

Comment: And to answer your question, use jquery migrate for your old code: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/  Your problem is some part of your code use deprecated/removed methods. Here, jquery.browser which has been removed

Comment: Why use setTimeout inside a setInterval?

Comment: @ABFORCE I'm very new in java script. I need to run a function every 5 second.

Comment: @nim4n, so the `setInterval` is adequate and there is no need for `setTimeout`

Comment: ok I removed that part

Answer (score 1):

This was probably because the `Fisheye` plugin made use of jQuery's old `$.browser` method, which was removed in later jQuery versions (1.9+ I think). If you still need this functionality, simply take the code below, wrap it in a file and link it in BEFORE the link to the Fisheye plugin.

This minified code will add back the functionality of `$.browser` using vendor info. Keep in mind, this won't work with browsers older than IE6, for that, just rewind you jQuery (if you really want to support something completely out of date!).

```
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
```

```js
/** jQuery.browser
 * @author J.D. McKinstry (2014)
 * @description Made to replicate older jQuery.browser command in jQuery versions 1.9+
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/wsqfbe4s/
 *
 * @extends jQuery
 * @namespace jQuery.browser
 * @example jQuery.browser.browser == 'browserNameInLowerCase'
 * @example jQuery.browser.version
 * @example jQuery.browser.mobile @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser['browserNameInLowerCase']
 * @example jQuery.browser.chrome @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.safari @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.opera @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.msie @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.mozilla @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.webkit @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.ua @returns navigator.userAgent String
 */
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile=
"iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0]):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&
/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0]))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser=
"Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0]))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):
/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])):
/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].match(/[0-9\.]{1,}/)[0])));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

var b = $.browser;
console.log($.browser);    //    see console, working example of jQuery Plugin
console.log($.browser.chrome);

for (var x in b) {
    if (x != 'init')
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<th />', { text: x }),
            $('<td />', { text: b[x] })
        ).appendTo($('table'));
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: .25em .5em; vertical-align: top; }
th { text-align: right; }

textarea { height: 500px; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```